# Spring Data JPA: Query Optimization

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

While working on a demo project I stuck at Spring Data JPA method based query. I want to search `top 5` results which contain my search team in name or address field.

For that my repository method is:

```
findTop5ByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrAddressContainingIgnoreCase(String name,
      String address);
```

I am just wondering is it most optimized way to achieve results or it can further optimize to improve performance?

Comment: Don't think you can do much better

Comment: You mean SPRING DATA JPA. The JPA API has none of this method naming nonsense.

Comment: You might consider to use a @Query annotation for this, as the method name is rather long-winded and may make the code that uses this function harder to read. This will also make it easier to tweak the query using a proper language that was designed for queries.

Answer (score 2):

The method:

```
findTop5ByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrAddressContainingIgnoreCase(String name, String address);
```

Generates a SQL like (Sql Server example):

```
select top 5 e.* from Entity e 
WHERE UPPER(e.name) LIKE UPPER('%SomeName%') OR UPPER(e.address) LIKE UPPER('%SomeAddress%')
```

In terms of SQL, this query is already really straightforward.

To improve the performance, you could create a index for this two fields or create two indexed new columns for `address` and `name`, both already saved with upper case. So you will not have to convert each information of address and name to upper case and compare.

Like:

```
id | name | name_search | address    | address_search
1  | John | JOHN        | Street Abc | STREET ABC
```

And the query:

```
findTop5ByNameSearchContainingOrAddressSearchContaining(
    String nameUpperCase, String addressUpperCase);
```